# Get message ID discord.py

Tags: discord.py

Is there a way to let the bot send a message and get the ID of the message, so you can delete it a few seconds later?
ps. discord.py

The only possible way I found was, to just delete the last sent message in the channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is two Q here:

1. yes there is a way to get the id for example:

```py
message = await ctx.send("hi")
message_id = message.id
```

2. to delete a message a few seconds later you can use `delete_after`
   for example:

```py
await ctx.send("hi",delete_after = 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

The channel.send() method has a kwarg exactly for this purpose, `delete_after`. You set it's value when sending a message and it will automatically delete the message after that time (in seconds). Here's the docs for the channel.send coroutine(/function) https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.send