# How do i automatically get message id when it is created?

Tags: discord.py

im trying to make it so that when my bot makes a message I get it's id
so I can work with it, how do I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get message ID discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68867185/get-message-id-discord-py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store a message when your bot sends it:

```py
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    message = await ctx.send("Test message")
```

Then you can get message ID using `message.id`.

```py
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    message = await ctx.send("Test message")
    await ctx.send(f"My last message ID: {message.id}")
```

Answer (score 0):

`channel.send(...)` actually returns you the message object, you may assign it to an variable and then work with it.

For example :

```py
@bot.command()
async def foo(ctx):
    sent_msg = await ctx.send("Hey!")
    await asyncio.sleep(1.5)
    await sent_msg.edit("Bye!")
```

The existing message was edited
[image]